# Inherit css value from body (parent) not working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm want to disable all css transitions using JavaScript. I added `transition: none` to the body (via JavaScript), but the elements in the body still have a transition.

Of course I can loop through all elements, and add `transition = 'none';`, but I'm sure there's a better way of temporary disabling the css transition of all elements. Here's a sample code:

#### JSFiddle

```js
var sample = document.getElementById('sample');

sample.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (document.body.style.transition === 'none') {
    document.body.style.transition = '';
  } else {
    document.body.style.transition = 'none';
  }
})
```

```css
#sample {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lawngreen;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}
#sample:hover {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="sample">Hover over me to move
  <br />Click to disable transition</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable the transitions?

Comment: do you have to use an ID instead of a class (for `#sample`)?

Comment: That's... not how the cascade in Cascading Style Sheets works. Changing something on `body` doesn't change anything in subsequent rules that define the same property. For instance, if you set the background color on body, it wouldn't change the background of #sample, would it?

Comment: @ExplosionPills This isn't my actual project, but I need to do it in my actual project. My project is more complex than this. lol

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That's an idea, I can add a class to all the `transition` elements, then loop those elements, and disable the transition. Thanks!

Comment: I understand, I'm just curious about what you need to do this for. You can pause animations in Chrome Inspector, for example.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan lol. You're right. Didn't think of it like that.

Comment: @ExplosionPills In my actual project, there will be mobile elements (like mobile menu) that have a transition. When the user changes to desktop version (resizes the browser), I don't want the mobile elements to transition out (slide away). I want it to disappear. Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new class name to the `body` or parent tag. Set transitions with the new parent selector `.animated #sample`:

```
<body class="animated">
    <div id="sample"></div>
</body>
```

... and the styles:

```
#sample {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lawngreen;
}

.animated #sample {
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

.animated #sample:hover {
    transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

To disable animations of all children just remove the `.animated` class from the body or parent tag.
Modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjxauu0h/1/

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to use a class on body so you can turn it on and off.

```js
var sample = document.getElementById('sample');
document.body.classList.add('transitioner');

sample.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (document.body.classList && document.body.classList.length) {
    document.body.classList.remove('transitioner');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.add('transitioner');
  }
  console.log(document.body.classList);
})
```

```css
#sample {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lawngreen;
}
.transitioner *{
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}
#sample:hover {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="sample">Hover over me to move
  <br />Click to disable transition</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sample = $('#sample');
var body = $('body');

sample.click(function() {
  body.toggleClass('notransition notransform');
});
```

```css
#sample {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lawngreen;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}
#sample:hover {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}

.notransition.notransform #sample {
  background: HotPink; 
}

.notransition * { 
  -webkit-transition: none !important; 
  -moz-transition: none !important; 
  -o-transition: none !important; 
  -ms-transition: none !important; 
  transition: none !important; 
} 

.notransform * { 
  -webkit-transform: none !important; 
  -moz-transform: none !important; 
  -o-transform: none !important; 
  -ms-transform: none !important; 
  transform: none !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample">Hover over me to move
  <br />Click to disable transition</div>
```